# No launchable projects are available for profiling

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have one project using VS 2012, when I try to run the "Start Performance Analysis" visual studio popup a message: No launchable projects are available for profiling.

I was able to run the profiler before, but don't remember if I changed any settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably trying to use the stock Visual Studio profiling tools. For Windows Phone applications, you have to use the profiler that comes with the SDK.

You can access it through `Debug` > `Start Windows Phone Application Analysis`.

Comment: Many thanks, it works, but I don't know if before I was using this option.